# Unable to post comments to a Pull Request using Github API

Tags: github-api

I am using [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment) to create comments to Pull Requests.

Following this:

I do not want to comment to specific line of code, rather a general comment to the PR itself. Say for example "Thanks for your PR @author"

```
// Using Joomla Http library that uses cURL internally
$http = new HttpRequest;

// The url variables below are set to the respective correct values
$url  = "https://api.github.com/repos/{$owner}/{$repo}/issues/{$number}/comments";

// Method: post($url, $data, $headers);
$resp = $http->post($url, array('body' => 'Thanks for your PR @author'), array('Authorization' => 'token ' . PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN));
```

This returns the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid request.\n\nFor 'links/0/schema', nil is not an object.",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment"
}
```

What I read in the docs, `links` is nowhere mentioned as a parameter for this request, so this is confusing me more.

PS: All other operations such as get reviews list, get comments list, delete a comment, add a label to PR, remove a label from PR etc. are working fine.

I found somewhere they say some additional authentication is required for commenting. I am not sure what that exactly mean and how I achieve that.

I have only [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) to validate my requests.

Please advise what I am missing.

Comment: Found the solution? Struck with the same problem.

Comment: Please check my answer @Rehan

Answer (score 1):

I was able to post the comment using `issues` api instead of `pull-request`

```php
    public function comment($message)
    {
        $http = new HttpRequest;

        $url     = "https://api.github.com/repos/{$this->owner}/{$this->repo}/issues/{$this->num}/comments";
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization' => 'token ' . GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        );
        $resp    = $http->post($url, json_encode(array('body' => $message)), $headers);

        return $resp->code == 201 ? $resp : null;
    }
```

The `HttpRequest` class in part of an internal library which is not much important here. You should be able to use any Http transport method.

Only important things are the **request url**, **headers** and **request data**.

Make sure the ACCESS_TOKEN in use is assigned the correct permissions. I can't remember it for now, will add here when I get a chance to look at it.